# Filtering and sorting doesn't work in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I know there were some questions related to this, but they couldn't help me out.

I have generated `GridView` which has `Sale` model, I added new column, which is from different table, it's named `price`. Now I want to add sorting and filtering to it, but somehow it doesn't work..

Here is my steps what I'm doing:

Step 1: adding function `getItemPrice` into my `Sale model`:

```
/* Gets item price*/
public function getItemPrice()
{
    return $this->item->price;
}
```

Step 2: defining price rule in `SaleSearch`model:

```
/**
* SaleSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Sale`.
*/
class SaleSearch extends Sale
{
public $price;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'item_id', 'sign'], 'integer'],
        [['customer_name', 'customer_surname', 'customer_phone', 'customer_email', 'code', 'comment'], 'safe'],
        [['price'], 'double'],
    ];
}
```

Step 3: adding `setSort()` into the same model and wrinting `joinWith` statement :

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Sale::find();
    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $query->joinWith('item');
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'customer_name',
            'customer_surname',
            'customer_phone',
            'customer_email',
            'code',
            'comment',
            'sign',
            'price' => [
                'asc' =>['tbl_item.price' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' =>['tbl_item.price' => SORT_DESC],
            ],
            'item_id' => [
                'asc' =>['item.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' =>['item.name' => SORT_DESC],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'item_id' => $this->item_id,
        'sign' => $this->sign,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_name', $this->customer_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_surname', $this->customer_surname])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_phone', $this->customer_phone])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_email', $this->customer_email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $this->code])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comment', $this->comment]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}

My `GridView`:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
            'attribute' => 'item_id',
            'value' => 'item.name',
        ],
        'code',
        'customer_name',
        'customer_surname',
        'customer_phone',
        [
            'attribute' => 'price',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->item->price;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'sign',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->sign == 1 ? 'Apmokėtas' : 'Neapmokėtas';
            },
        ],

        // 'customer_email:email',
        //  'comment:ntext',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

After writing code like that, my all `GridView` now has no sorting or filtering at all. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the whole `search()` method?

Comment: Your code tells that you should get sorting for `price` only. Is this the case?

Comment: I want to add `sorting` and `filtering` for all the existing fields :/

Comment: Your `Gridview`?

Comment: your attribute name is `Kaina` not price so, `$dataProvider->sort->attributes['Kaina'] = []` may work, i guess.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Oh god, thank you! Finally! Write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `Sort` object with your code. By default it prepares sorting for all attributes. If you only want to add one field to sorting do this:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['price'] = [
        'asc' => ['tbl_item.price' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['tbl_item.price' => SORT_DESC],
        'label' => 'Item price'
    ];
```

This way you don't override the default behavior.

Comment: So I should delete my written code and leave it by default, then try to use yours?

Comment: Replace your `$dataProvider->setSort(...` with my version.

Comment: It didn't worked. I've edited my `search method` in the post. You can see how it looks like now. All the sorting works for all atrributes, except `price`.

Comment: Show the controller's action as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute name is `Kaina` not `price`. So,

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['Kaina'] = [
    'asc' => ['tbl_item.price' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['tbl_item.price' => SORT_DESC],
    'label' => 'Item price'
];
```